# Design Material Design Lite Grid with cards to look like Google Keep

Tags: html, css, django, material-design

I am using Django in combination with Material Design Lite.

I have accomplished a responsive layout where the cards that I generate scale with the width of the screen. 
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

This is a snippet of the rendered HTML with some cards removed to keep it readeable.

```html
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
    

    <div class="mdl-grid">
        
        <!-- Start of card !-->
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone ">
        <div class="stories mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__supporting-text">&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&quot;&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing e</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__title-text">
        Tales
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"
        href="/1/details">View details</a>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of card !-->

        
        <!-- Start of card !-->
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone ">
        <div class="stories mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__supporting-text">&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&quot;&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing e</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__title-text">
        fezfez
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"
        href="/2/details">View details</a>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of card !-->

        
        <!-- Start of card !-->
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone ">
        <div class="stories mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__supporting-text">&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&quot;&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing e</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__title-text">
        ffffum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis n
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"
        href="/3/details">View details</a>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of card !-->

      
        
        <!-- Start of card !-->
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone ">
        <div class="stories mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__supporting-text">ff</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__title-text">
        fze
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"
        href="/34/details">View details</a>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of card !-->
    </div>

    </main>
```

The uncompiled HTML:

```html
  <div class="mdl-grid">
        {% for story in all_stories_list %}
        <!-- Start of card !-->
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone ">
        <div class="stories mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__supporting-text">{{story.story_plot}}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__title-text">
        {{story.story_name}}
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"
        href="/{{story.id}}/details">View details</a>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of card !-->

        {% endfor %}
```

This is the CSS:

```html
.stories {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width:auto;
}

.mdl-card__title {
  background-color: #156767;

}

.mdl-card__title-text {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.mdl-card__supporting-text{
  color:white;
}
```

What I would like to accomplish now is that the cards have the same amount of space between them vertically, so that there is a fixed whitespace between the cards. How would I accomplish this? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not read through your design though, just wanted to share how I did it.

[How mine looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdZTM.png)

I just checked Google Keep, I believe it is what you're looking for. The main idea is not to put the cards in a table, but in some columns. All the cards within the column in fact has the same width, then we can just distribute the cards among the columns.

First, my html template:

```
{% load mod_filter %}
<div class="content" align="center">
    {% for counter in "0123" %}
    <div class="col" style="width:24%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
        {% for item in result %}
        {% ifequal forloop.counter|is_in_col:4 forloop.parentloop.counter %}
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-content white-text" align="left">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" align="left">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I used an `is_in_col` filter to distribute the items according to their indexes. You need to create this filter too. Create a folder called `templatetags` in your app, create an empty `__init__.py` and `mod_filter.py` inside.

mod_filter.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def is_in_col(num, val):
    return (num - 1) % val + 1   # forloop counter starts with 1
```

Make sure you have your app put in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. Restart your server after that. It should be easy to change to other numbers of column.

There is a flaw in my design though. As it separates the same number of cards into each column, if some of them are longer and you're unlucky, some of the columns can get much longer than others.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the issue has been solved by now. I'll mark your answer as helpful for the effort.